# Proving an interpolation inequality on Holder Space

Tags: real-analysis, interpolation

I want to show that for 0 < µ < ß ≤ 1,

[f]<sub>µ</sub> ≤ 2 sup|f|<sup>1 - µ/ß</sup> [f]<sub>ß</sub><sup>µ/ß</sup>

where [f]<sub>µ</sub> := sup<sub>x≠y</sub> |f(y) - f(x)|/|y-x|<sup>µ</sup>

I don't know how to proceed with this question.
Any help would be welcome!

Comment: Hint: Write $|f(y)-f(x)|=|f(y)-f(x)|^{1-\mu/\beta}|f(y)-f(x)|^{\mu/\beta}$.

Comment: Thanks, that helps!

just a follow up, [f]_µ ≤ M sup|f|<sup>1 - µ/ß</sup> [f]<sub>H<sub>ß</sub></sub><sup>µ/ß</sup> would use the same approach?

Comment: Dude I have no idea what you have written there. If you want to do math, it would be to your greatest benefit to learn how to write in LaTeX soon. I think that this website even has a tutorial on how to use it, you just have to search it.

Comment: All i was asking is that in the first equation, on RHS, the second element has subscript H_ß instead of ß?